# If I did not know $|\Sigma_A|=n!$ in advance, how would I approach this problem to determine $|\Sigma_A|$?

Tags: combinatorics

> Suppose that $|A|=n$ and that $\Sigma_A$ be the set of permutations of $A$, then determine the cardinality of $\Sigma_A$.

I found that the reasoning below is not rigorous and convincing enough for me to trust since it is not built up on any mathematical principle. Maybe I have not learned anything in combinatorics and just exposed to some elementary set theory, so I'm unable to understand the underlying theorems/principles behind such *everyday words* as *choose*.

> Since $|A|=n$, then assume $A=\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\}$. Let $f:A\to A$ be a bijection, and thus $f$ is a permutation of $A$. We have $n$ ways to choose an element for $f(a_1)$, $n-1$ ways to choose an element for $f(a_2)$, and so on. Thus we have $n\cdot(n-1)\cdots1=n!$ ways to generate $f$. Thus $\Sigma_A=n!$.

I also found that the proof is quite straightforward by induction on $n$ if I know $|\Sigma_A|=n!$ in advance, but I can not imagine any way to figure out the intuition behind $|\Sigma_A|=n!$. I'm sure that I would be beaten if I did not know the result.

My questions:

1. Is there any intuition behind the formula $|\Sigma_A|=n!$.
2. If I did not know $|\Sigma_A|=n!$ in advance, how would I visualize/sketch a diagram to determine $|\Sigma_A|$?

Comment: Your second question is very odd. You just provided a proof (in fact, two). If you do not know the answer, you find that argument, that is how you figure it out.

Comment: What do you mean by "Instead, it uses every day words such as choose and so on."? That is generally how one writes a proof...with words.

Comment: Hi @A.Pongrácz , that's my question: How do I find the argument?

Comment: Hi @Math1000 , I have not learned combinatorics and just exposed to elementary set theory recently, so I do not understand the underlying principles behind such *every day words*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I did not know $|\Sigma_A|=n!$ in advance, how would I visualize/sketch a diagram to determine $|\Sigma_A|$?

The common way to conjecturize a result you have no hint about is to check what happens for small values of $n$.

It takes only a few seconds to find out that $|\Sigma_{A_1}|=1$ (where $|A_n|=n$), $|\Sigma_{A_2}|=2$ and $|\Sigma_{A_3}|=6$.

A little effort for listing all the permutations of $A_4$ might take two minutes; Alternatively you can reason by noticing that a permutation of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ is a permutation of $\{1,2,3\}$ with a $4$ added at any of $4$ possible spots (and you are already on your way to the proof by induction).

Once you get $|\Sigma_{A_4}|=24$, you should recognize the !-pattern.